# Extract Kernel from Running System

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Is it possible to get the kernel image (bzImage, vmlinuz, etc.) from a running system by reading through the system's memory?

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: Ok, but why do you need the kernel image from a running system?

Comment: Have you already tried talking to the administrator of the PXE server? It seems like the environment the running system is in is highly secured, and if you start sniffing, you might trip other security mechanisms. In secure environments, "hacking/sniffing without proper authorization" can be a very serious offense, up to possibly causing you to lose your job immediately. Make very sure you have appropriate management blessing to whatever you're doing.Your boss might be able to just tell the PXE server admin to give you the boot image files you need.

Comment: Why was this Q closed? Since the booting system is actually fetching the kernel image with PXE, there certainly should be a way to fetch and save it. Also, try to keep it technical; It's only OP's business if they're going to lose their job.

Comment: @mosvy I agree. There are plenty of legitimate reasons for wanting this question answered, like the disk failing and the system still running. The user may be able to recover it if he can get the kernel image from the system and put it on a new drive or something.

Comment: Agreed. At the very least *"Unclear what you're asking"* is incorrect.  What the OP is asking for is very clear indeed.  I suspect people have fallen into the trap of knowing that this is impossible and believing such questions should be closed.  I was going to write up an answer on why this is impossible but have been blocked from doing so.

Comment: @user As this question has not yet been re-opened I can't leave you a proper answer. But the short version is that no you can't.  At a very low level, all programs appear to re-write themselves.  Eg global variables are overwritten with new values. 
 The Kernel isn't a program as such, but the same rule applies.  If you were to copy the kernel out of memory, you would get the current state of the kernel (after booting and many thousand operations have taken place).  Image files store the memory state of the kernel *before* any operations have taken place.

Comment: @PhilipCouling So does the kernel compression (gz, lzo, lz4, etc.) only affect the size on disk? It doesn't actually reduce memory requirements or affect run speed?

Comment: @user Correct, the kernel image is machine code to be executed by the processor.  The processor can't interpret gz or any other compression on the fly and the a compressed kernel needs to be decompressed before the kernel boots.

Comment: I guess that the image is changing the hw address (MAC) -- notice that on linux you can obtain the original hw address of an interface with `ethtool -P ifname`. Don't blame me if some mouth-breather who relies on MAC "authentication" is going to fire you for "hacking" ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this isn't possible.

The basic problem is that despite the fact the kernel image is loaded directly into memory, this image is changed the moment the kernel is booted.  While the kernel isn't really a program, many of the rules about the way a program is compiled / loaded into memory still apply.

---

Take the following C code as an example:

```
char x=5

int some_function() {
    x=100;
}
```

The first line `x=5` tells the compiler put the number 5 in a byte somewhere in memory for use latter.  When the program runs, this byte will be loaded directly into memory along with everything else.

The later line `x=100` tells the compiler to write machine code which, when executed will overwrite the original value.  So if you extracted the running program from memory and de-compiled it you might see something like this

```
char x=100

int some_function() {
    x=100;
}
```

*Effectivly, the running program has re-written itself.*

---

Similarly to this, user-land programs are stored in [ELF format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format).  When you run a userland program, the program loader has to assemble the program image from many pieces.  Now the rules for the Kernel are a little different but there is a parallel with [`modprobe`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modprobe) which loads other files into the running Kernel's memory space.

---

So while you might find a way to dump the entire memory of your Kernel, the result won't actually look much like the original Kernel image and certainly not enough to boot from it.

Here I'm afraid your *best* option is to go to the sysadmins and ask them for a copy, or ask for access.